# How to generate aws-exports.js with existing User Pool in AWS Cognito?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I can not generate aws-exports.js file using existing User Pool of AWS Cognito. How to do it?

I tried to generate aws-exports.js file with creating new User Pool of AWS Cognito. But it is not correct thing that I want. Also, I found some explanation of problem on github: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/779#issuecomment-458080804

Comment: Have you read this? https://medium.com/@danielcender/use-a-custom-cognito-user-pool-with-aws-appsync-3d0c82f3010b It should help.

Answer (score 13):

From [this page in the docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-authentication-resource):

> If you want to re-use an existing authentication resource from AWS (e.g. Amazon Cognito UserPool or Identity Pool), update Amplify.configure() method with the following information.

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region 
        // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
        identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',

        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: false,

        // OPTIONAL - Configuration for cookie storage
        // Note: if the secure flag is set to true, then the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol
        cookieStorage: {
        // REQUIRED - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
            domain: '.yourdomain.com',
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie path
            path: '/',
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie expiration in days
            expires: 365,
        // OPTIONAL - See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
            sameSite: "strict" | "lax",
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie secure flag
        // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
            secure: true
        },

        // OPTIONAL - customized storage object
        storage: MyStorage,

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set key value pairs that can be passed to Cognito Lambda Triggers
        clientMetadata: { myCustomKey: 'myCustomValue' },

         // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
        oauth: {
            domain: 'your_cognito_domain',
            scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
        }
    }
});

// You can get the current config object
const currentConfig = Auth.configure();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate the code. You can simply add this code to the `index.js` or `App.js` file.

#react-native #aws-cognito

```
   import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

   Amplify.configure({
   Auth: { 
       identityPoolId: xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,
       region: xx-xxxx-x,
       userPoolId: xx-xxxx-x_xxxxxxxxx,
       userPoolWebClientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
   }});


/**
 * You can get this ID's from AWS console panel.
 * identityPoolId      - AWS > Cognito > Federated Identities > Select the identity pool > Sample code > Get AWS Credentials.
 * region              - xx-xxxx-x
 * userPoolId          - AWS > Cognito > User pools (Select the user pool) > User pool ID
 * userPoolWebClientId - AWS > Cognito > User pools (Select the user pool) > Select App Integration tab > App client list > Select the App client name > Client ID
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running from the command line in your project directory:

```
amplify import auth
```

and then after you go through the steps to import an existing user pool, run:

```
amplify push
```

and your aws-exports.js file will get updated with the right connection params.

Comment: Please use the correct formatting (e.g. code blocks) and specify a source / documentation if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it:
Amplify.configure({
Auth: {
identityPoolId: 'xxxxxx',
region: 'xxxxx',
userPoolId: 'xxxxxxx',
userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxx'
}
});

Comment: Could you add a bit more information to your answer? The answer does not look like trying to generate a file.